# BASH & MYSQL - logg mysql problems during running of a bash/sh script

Tags: mysql, bash, error-logging

I am building a bash script that makes a lot of use of mysql.
Now I want to add it a possibility to log down any comments/errors that come from the database. 
lets admit the simple case.

```
mysql -uuser -ppass dbase <<EOF
insert into table (col) values ("$val");
EOF
```

how would this look with logging to /var/log/mylamescript ?
I want to log warnings, errors, etc ... anything except "successful"

Comment: I do not want to log the transactions, I want to log errors and warnings regarding the transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to redirect the standard error appending to your log file:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass dbase <<EOF 2>> /var/log/mylamescript 
    insert into table (col) values ("$val");
EOF
```

Comment: I was trying to see what mysql --debug is saying, but I get mysql: ERROR: Option 'debug' used, but is disabled

Comment: @eichertc `2>>` means appending the standard error to a file. MySQL emits both errors and warnings on the standard error. Regarding the `--debug` option you need a debug enabled MySQL (you can configure it during compilation). Check also `--debug-info`.